# mysql error, right syntax to use near ''

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a problem with this SQL code. I want to create a trigger, here it is.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `blog_after_insert` AFTER UPDATE ON `agent`

FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN     
DECLARE costvalue INTEGER default 0;

IF (OLD.PacketStatusType_Id!=NEW.PacketStatusType_Id) THEN

        IF (OLD.Packet_Cost IS NULL) THEN
            SET costvalue = OLD.Packet_Cost;
        ELSE
            SET costvalue = OLD.Packet_SMSCount;
        END IF;

           IF (costvalue IS NOT NULL) THEN
               CALL tcksms_packet_update_proc(OLD.Transaction_Id,OLD.PacketStatusType_Id,costvalue,-1);
           ELSE
               CALL tcksms_packet_update_proc(OLD.Transaction_Id,OLD.PacketStatusType_Id,0,-1);
           END IF;


        DECLARE COST_VALUE_NEW INT DEFAULT 0;

        IF (NEW.Packet_Cost IS NULL) THEN
            SET COST_VALUE_NEW = NEW.Packet_Cost;
        ELSE
            SET COST_VALUE_NEW = NEW.Packet_SMSCount;
        END IF;

           IF (COST_VALUE_NEW IS NOT NULL) THEN
               CALL tcksms_packet_update_proc(NEW.Transaction_Id,NEW.PacketStatusType_Id,COST_VALUE_NEW,1);
           ELSE
               CALL tcksms_packet_update_proc(NEW.Transaction_Id,NEW.PacketStatusType_Id,0,1);
           END IF;

        ELSE



        END IF;

   END IF;
END
```

But i get this;

Error

SQL query:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `blog_after_insert` AFTER UPDATE ON `agent` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN DECLARE costvalue INTEGER default 0;
```

> MySQL said: Documentation > #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 5

That line is 
I tried deleting spaces, made combinations of apostrophes (' and `), deleted and rewrited some lines manually but can't make it work, what is wrong with this code?

Comment: I cannot see the delimiter command before the trigger definition. Did you use it?

Comment: No, I didn't use it, do I have to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `delimiter` command before and after the `create trigger` command, otherwise the semicolons terminating the commands within the trigger body will confuse mysql. See mysql's documentation on [defining stored programs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-programs-defining.html), which also has examples how to use the `delimiter` command.

Comment: Thanks, I've seen some mistakes in the code, now adding delimiter command and making changes.

Comment: I have not checked the entire code. If the use of the delimiter solves this question, then pls ask any follow-up questions in their separate topic(s).